# Do managed programming languages make use of hardware virtualization?

Tags: java, .net, mono, managed, vm-implementation

Do the virtual machines that run programs written in managed languages (eg. .Net, Mono or Java) make use of the same virtualization technologies as virtual machine applications (eg. VirtualBox or VMWare)? Particularly; do they make use of Intel hardware virtualization (VT-x)?

If not, why? Is this because of some fundamental difference between the concepts (they just happen to share a name but are entirely different) or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have correctly stated,

> they just happen to share a name but are entirely different.

Virtualized hardware is perceived by the software as being indistinguishable from the actual hardware. It has exactly the same architecture, down to a quite low level, at which the abstraction layer of the virtualization is crossed.

This is not at all the goal of a VM for a managed language, which creates a virtual environment specific to that language, and identical on all hardware platforms.